# Bootstrap responsive image with CTA in grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 5. I have the following:

```
<div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap overflow-auto g-0 align-items-center my-cards">
    <div class="col-5 col-md-2 me-3" data-card-id="25">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="56ba4956ac082d3c3b038a2542c8e756.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-md-2 me-3" data-card-id="35">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="9ca7688e7dd342bcd3669b4281107df3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-md-2 me-3" data-card-id="24">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="ff2ca738f2463d1a8db77224fd27a1b6.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-md-2 me-3" data-card-id="2">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="5fa69e886f502187e8a66aeeb3be6573.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-md-2 me-3" data-card-id="13">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="74409b63ea174d76157c97198afadd55.png">
    </div>
  <div class="col-5 col-md-2 rounded text-center" style="border: 4px dashed #ddd">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-decoration-none text-muted" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#manage_cards">
      <i class="fas fa-fw fa-plus-circle"></i> Add card
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the image size is fluid. Images all have original dimension 360x225px.

**Problem**
The image size are different because it's responsive with class `img-fluid`, so I have set it to look bigger on mobile with `col-5` and smaller with `col-md-2` on desktop. There is this button called "Add Card", which I want it to be same size as the image in terms of height and width, with or without image present, which means there could be time when there is no image, and it's just "Add Card".

Of course right now the "Add Card" button is small and not as big as card in terms of padding, height and width. How do I make "Add Card" as responsive, same size as other images?

Answer (score 1):

You give the raw div a class `align-items-stretch`  instead of `align-items-center` and all flex boxes will have the same height.
And to center add card text in the box you add classes `d-flex justify-content-center` to the add card div.

Comment: Almost there. These classes worked well. When there is no image, the "Add card" div is small again.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) like this:

```
//get image height
let imgHeight = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelectorAll('.col-5.col-md-2.me-3')[0]).getPropertyValue('height');
//set this height to to button
document.querySelectorAll('.col-5.col-md-2 > button')[0].setAttribute('height', imgHeight);
```

Comment: This doesn’t work when there’s no image. There’s nowhere to compute from

Comment: Consider placing a dummy transparent image with images dimension (360x225px).